# Node.js / API: Need to access request specific information through the application

Tags: node.js, api, session, oauth-2.0, access-token

We currently have sessions disabled.

Instead, each request is sent with an `access_token` so that at the end of the request, nothing persists to the next request.

> ie. Request received --> Validate access_token and set associated user as "current user"

---

The first issue we came across was the ability to access this use throughout the application.

> eg. We need current user id in the repository

Our solution was to use node.js' [domain](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html). This didn't work out so well because when concurrent requests happened from different users the domain would be overwritted -- it was shared.

What I need is:

1. A globally accessible (or by require) object that can contain a
   couple parameters I assign to it.
2. This globally accessible object to be unique for each request so that any given request could retrieve the information pertaining to itself.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to just attach it to your request object (do it in some middleware if you're using express).

`req.access_token = 'get_the_token_and_put_it_here';`

Now it's accessible from everywhere you can access your request object.

Comment: I need the request object from other layers though. Is there a way to access this without passing it through each layer?

Comment: You can't avoid passing *some* information down through your layers, either all the data or some type of identifier. I suggest you persist the information to some external storage (e.g. database); alternatively you can create a module from which you can put and get the information you want using some type of identifier (acting like a datastore essentially). Note, with the second option if your node process dies your information is lost.